# Why do I get a "Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected" error message at site?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Works fine at my dev. PC, However once I run it on the site I get:

**Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected**

```
byte[] keyBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(PasswordHash, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SaltKey)).GetBytes(256 / 8);

var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged() { Mode = CipherMode.CBC, Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros };

var encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(VIKey));
```

Comment: Please do not make edits that jumble lines together.

Comment: Is it the space between RijndaelManaged() and { Mode = ... ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll get this if you're using a machine that only has .NET 2.0 or .NET 3.0 installed, and thus only a C# 2 compiler.

This code:

```
var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged() { Mode = CipherMode.CBC, ... };
```

... uses an *object initializer* which was introduced into C# 3. (It also uses `var`, which was introduced at the same time.)

I suspect you just need to upgrade your web site to a more recent version of .NET.

You could validate that this is the problem by simply having a statement of:

```
var x = "";
```

I suspect you'll find that fails with an error that the compiler can't find the `var` type - whereas the C# 3+ compiler will use implicit typing instead.